# Simple file upload to Django via HTTP request

Tags: django, upload

I'm really confused with the process of uploading a file (image or pdf in my case) to a Django app programmatically (via HTTP POST or PUT request). I've read the doc but I must admit it hasn't helped me get through. The most confusing part to me is the template (and form) : why do I need to specify a template and form in the view ?

I just want to send a file to a directory, and I'd like to know what exactly is needed in order to do so on the Django part as well as on the request part (content-type... ?)

I'd be really grateful to anyone able to show me some direction here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what doc you're reading, so it's hard for us to tell what you mean. But if you're planning on doing a programmatic upload, you *don't* need a template, of course. You do however need some code that accepts the POST and processes the upload: you can do that with a form, or simply access the data in `request.FILES` and do what you want with it yourself.

**Edit** It's true that that page doesn't make any reference to uploading programmatically, because most people's use cases are uploading through the browser, via a form. But the page does explain how to [handle uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files), which is the only bit that you need.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry for the missing info : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/